# MacOS port become blocked

Tags: macos, network, firewall

I have tried setting up Packet Filter on macOS 10.15.5.

- I develop software.
- I am hosting some services via supervisord.
- It has a user interface on port 9001 running to reset/start/stop services.

For all time long it worked well and I was able to access that UI on the local network. I ran a nmap from my Windows PC targeting my development Mac. After this, on nmap my opened ports were displayed as tcpwraped, (i am not running any firewall on my dev mac). I am not able to access my dev machine from the windows pc anymore. It says Unable to connect, though those ports are visible from the nmap.

All ports are accessible from my other MacBook, but on my PC all ports are NOT accessible.

Is there any way to understand what happened?

Comment: Your question seems to contradict itself. You state that you're setting up "packet filter" (i.e. a firewall), and then you write that you're "not running any firewall". So there seems to be some information missing here... can you detail what exactly you set up in pf?

Comment: Additionally, you say that "*all ports are accessible from my other MacBook, but on my PC...ports are NOT accessible.*"  This points to an issue with your PC, not your Mac.  Is it possible that the PC (Windows) firewall (or 3rd party virus/security software) has blocked those ports from outgoing traffic?

Comment: @Allan good point, I would check it out tomorrow and post any update

Comment: @jksoegaard I meant I was setting up a packet filter, as a try to fix my problem, but it did not, so I reverted my changes and turned off the firewall. My initial setup is without the firewall

Comment: @Allan checked this today, seems I am not able to access any of me machines from my Windows PC, looks like it it realy a problem with closed outgoing connection from my PC. You had a good point, thanks!

Comment: @Allan the problem was my VPN setup on my PC, probably nmap messed something, I fixed everything by reinstalling my VPN. If you post your suggestion as answer I would accept it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for me here was my **VPN** setup, I had to reinstall my **Nord VPN**, and reconnect in order to be able to access my **Mac** on **local network**.

Also, I would suggest using some **PacketFilter firewall manager** on the Mac machine. I use Murus and it seems to be pretty good for my requirements.

Thanks everyone who helped me to figure this out quickly.